# Why ajax is not working after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube-api

I'm using [Youtube SPF](https://youtube.github.io/spfjs/) for my web page and I have a lot of js and they work as expect it's okey so far but my ajax is not working by clicking for example after page loaded if I click any page the page has loaded with ajax but nothing is work..and I want to share with you my instance js which is not working after ajax

for example this code is not work after ajax

```
$(".all-content-tab .tab-content,.trustyou-tab .tab-content").find(".tab-pane:first").addClass("active");
```

or this

```
$(".add-active").find('li:first').addClass("active");
```

and I change my all event function with this

```
$(document).on("click","#element",function(){
//
})
```

instead of this

```
$("#element").on("click",function(){
//
})
```

and last thing

my spf function

```
$(function () {
    spf.init();
    NProgress.configure({ showSpinner: false });
    $(document).on('spfrequest', function (event) {
        NProgress.set(0.4);
    });

    $(document).on('spfprocess', function (event) {
        NProgress.set(0.6);
        NProgress.set(0.8);
    });

    $(document).on('spfdone', function (event) {
        NProgress.set(1.0);
        NProgress.done();
    });

    $(document).on('spfhistory', function (event) {
        NProgress.set(0.7);
        NProgress.set(0.9);
        NProgress.set(1.0);
        NProgress.done();
    });
});
```

how can I fix this problem ? I read all document but nothing could I do

Comment: Checked console for errors? What do you see there?

Comment: @Rahi http://prntscr.com/eh2axr only this

Comment: and can I trigger my js function after page loaded with ajax ?

Comment: Just an idea, but is your JS code external? You might want to keep it on the page itself. Sometimes JS does not like being loaded after the fact.

Comment: I call my all js function again when ajax loaded is there any risk to affecting performance ?